# How to implement a retry logic in pattern match?

Tags: scala

This is my function that used to call another api, I want to do a retry when I got some specific exception(TimeoutException, etc) for 3 times, how can do that? Thanks for help!

```
 determinationService.getTax(getRequest, runID) match {
            case Success(getResponse) =>
                LOGGER.info("Following response received from determination service:")
                LOGGER.info(getTaxResponse.toString)
                    ...
            case Failure(exception) =>
                LOGGER.error(
                    "AppName:{} RunID:{} Grpc error when calling Determination service: {}",
                    Array(LoggingConstant.APP_NAME, runID, exception): _*
                )
                //do retry here
}
```

unit test

```
 val determinationServiceMock = mock[DeterminationService]
        doReturn(Failure(new TimeOutException())).when(determinationServiceMock).getTax(any(), any())
```

Comment: Move the logic to its own function so you can just call it recursively and keep track of the number of iterations.

Comment: Hi @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I'm new to scala, can you tell me what that looks like? thanks

Comment: Something similar to what Alin posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a result type of `Unit` you could do:

```
  @tailrec
  def someDef(retry: Int = 0): Unit = {
    determinationService.getTax(getRequest, runID) match {
      case Success(getResponse) =>
        LOGGER.info("Following response received from determination service:")
        LOGGER.info(getTaxResponse.toString)
        // ...
      case Failure(exception) =>
        LOGGER.error(
          "AppName:{} RunID:{} Grpc error when calling Determination service: {}",
          Array(LoggingConstant.APP_NAME, runID, exception): _*
        )
        exception match {
          case _: TimeoutException if retry < 3 => someDef(retry + 1)
          case _                                => // ...
        }
    }
  }
```

**Note**: your actual code might not be tail-recursive, just this snippet is.

Comment: Thanks for help Alin! I had one more question for unit test, is there a way to implement this
1.first time got TimeoutException 2.exception gone, calling api success.    

I edited the code, put what I have for unit test above

Comment: nvm, I know how to do it, thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's doable, but that seems like a new question.